# Lodash - extending objects from array with nested object information

Tags: functional-programming, lodash

Im kinda getting into functional programming. My problem it is about how you can map information from nested data.

I have an array of companies.

```
[  
  {
    _id: 123,
    name: "Company"
  }, 
  {
    _id: 789,
    name: "Company"
  }
];
```

I have an array of teams.

```
[  
  {
    _id: 555,
    name: "Team name A",
    companyId: 123
  }, 
  {
    _id: 666,
    name: "Team name B",
    companyId: 123
  },
  {
    _id: 777,
    name: "Team name C",
    companyId: 789
  }
];
```

I would like to put teams into company object for every company. The expect result would be:

```
[  
  {
    _id: 123,
    name: "Company",
    teams: [  
             {
               _id: 555,
               name: "Team name A",
               companyId: 123
             }, 
             {
               _id: 666,
               name: "Team name B",
               companyId: 123
             }
           ]
  }, 
  {
    _id: 789,
    name: "Company",
    teams: [  
             {
               _id: 777,
               name: "Team name A",
               companyId: 789
             }
           ]
  }
];
```

My solution has been to do it in several steps:

```
teamsGroupedByCompany = _.group(teams, 'companyId');

var findTeamsByCompanyId = function(groupedTeams, companyId){
    return _.chain(groupedTeams)
            .find(function(value, key){
               return companyId == key;
            })
            .flatten()
            .defaults([])
            .value();
}

_.map(companies, function(company){
    company.team = findTeamsByCompanyId(teamsGroupedByCompany, company._id);
})
```

Can it be done in a chaining way or I have to make higher order functions to deal with these kind of issues? Currently Im using lodash.

Here is the jsbin https://jsbin.com/buqiji/edit?js,console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will do the trick.

```
companies = _.chain(companies)
.map(function(company) {
  company.teams = _.filter(teams, {'companyId': company._id});
  return company;
})
.value();
```

Here's a JsBin: https://jsbin.com/cudoheziyi/1/edit?js,console

Answer (score 1):

My solution is similar to yours. I'm doing it in two steps as well.

You already have `teamsGroupedByCompany` so you can use that to assign teams to each company directly without having to do `findTeamsByCompanyId`. Here's my solution:

(assume `companies` and `teams` are already initialized)

```
const groupedTeams = _.groupBy(teams, 'companyId');
const combined = _.map(companies, c => {
  c.teams = groupedTeams[c._id] || [];
  return c;
});
```

http://jsbin.com/mixewo/1/edit?js,console